# How to use Ubuntu to recover data from an old Windows XP laptop with a broken hard drive?

Tags: downloads

I want to transfer data from an old laptop in which the hard drive doesn't work.

I have:

- Old laptop = 7yr old Toshiba laptop - Windows XP, was fast, **hard drive doesn't work**
- Newer laptop = 3yr olf Toshiba laptop - Windows 7, quite slow, works.
- SATA/USB converter = External 2.5" Sata HDD USB connector

Planning on getting:

- New drive = New 80GB+ 2.5" Sata HDD hard drive

The SATA/USB converter says it's compatible with Win2000/Vista/7/8 but not XP!

Is it feasible to download Ubuntu to the new drive via the new laptop & the SATA/USB converter then fit that drive into the old laptop and boot up with Ubuntu, then plug the SATA/USB converter with the broken hard drive, into the old laptop and transfer "all" the data including WinXP from the broken hard drive to the new drive?

Or alternatively, download Ubuntu to the new drive via the NEWER laptop & the SATA/USB converter then use that to boot up that newer laptop with Ubuntu, then replace the new drive with the broken hard drive from the old laptop and transfer "all" the data including WinXP from the broken hard drive to the hard drive within the newer laptop then replace the broken hard drive with the new drive and transfer the data to it via the SATA/USB converter, then fit the new drive into the old laptop?

---

Firstly, sorry for not making the question easy to understand, I did read and edit it many times, and did consider numbering the broken drive, before posting.   I guess it was the reading many times that made it clear in my mind.

Secondly I'd be interested to know if any others find that Win7 is slower than WinXP.

The broken hard drive has the famous “click noise of death” including when it is fitted into the SATA/USB converter via the newer laptop.   I doubt if that hard drive still works.

wilf - When you refer to "disk" I guess you mean to acquire a blank CD disk.   I have never done that before so would be curious if there is anything I need to know in advance.

By the way I found Ubuntu from http://geekyprojects.com/storage/how-to-recover-data-even-when-hard-drive-is-damaged/

---

I searched for Operating Instructions for Ubuntu Rescue Remix and the best place I've found is http://www.geekyprojects.com/storage/how-to-recover-data-even-when-hard-drive-is-damaged/

Comment: it was so hard to understand.

Comment: You missed to give a number to **the broken hard drive**. That made it hard to read. But your (1) method is feasible (though it's hard), your (2) is not.

Comment: What do you mean by 'broken' on the first drive - is WinXP just broke, or is it the drive itself - if so, is input/output errors or what? :-s

Comment: I've just made the eleventy-first attempt to make this question easier to understand.  I think I almost nailed it.

Comment: And realised this isn't really an Ubuntu issue at all - the problem is how to get data off a broken hard drive on an old Windows XP laptop.  Ubuntu is just one possible tool that can be used when attempting to recover data.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a USB stick, or disk with Ubuntu on, to boot **1**, from which I could work out whether **1**'s hard drive still works - It would be a 'Live' environment of Ubuntu, with disk and file managers, which should work, and mean youw would not need to install anything.

Basically, your first method should work OK, but if you do all the stuff from a Ubuntu session on a USB stick or disk, then you would not wipe the Ubuntu install on the **4** hard drive, and could copy all the stuff from **1's** broken drive to the new **4** drive form the Live Ubuntu session.

This will all depend on the type of 'broken' you mean on the first drive...

---

Here is a step-by-step guide *(tested on Windows 7 Pro 64bit)*:

First download the Ubuntu 14.04 (latest version of Ubuntu, main version 32bit) from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso). This should be perfectly capable of recovering any data etc from your computer, and anything else can likely be installed easily. Note this download will take a while, and will require at least 1 Gigabyte in space.

Then open where it was downloaded to, right click on the 'ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso' File and click 'Properties'. You should be able to see something like the following, with similar sizes *(note, not all computers and programs may get the exact same size)*:

[image: The properties window should show the size of the file]

The iso file should be around 970MiB (1017118 KiloBytes) in size - if the download had stopped suddenly try again *(I managed to download it fully on the second try using Firefox)*, or use the [torrent download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent) *(you can do this with [BitTorrent](http://www.bittorrent.com/bittorrent-free), you can exit it when has downloaded)*

If you are still not sure the file has been downloaded properly, you can check the MD5SUM of the file, using [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows), the program available [here](http://www.nullriver.com/products), and [this file](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS) with what the MD5SUMs should be *(use the one for `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso`)*.

You can then burn the DVD to a disc. There are instructions on that [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows). You should be able to use the Windows program to do this, you shouldn't need a third-party (other companies) program to do it *(if you do, you can use [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/), instructions on using it are [here](http://www.eugenecomputergeeks.com/Chat-FAQ/How-do-I-Burn-Ubuntu-to-a-CD-from-Windows.html) )*.

Insert a blank DVD (ignore any autorun options), then right click on the downloaded iso file and click 'Burn disc image'. Select the Disc burner, and tick 'Verify after burning' so the disc is checked afterwards. When finished it should show:

[image: Disc burned sucessfully]
<sup>**Note:** Writing on the disc what you have put on it (ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso) and the date is great for future reference. Permanent markers work fine for this.</sup>

You can then check the disk to see if it has been burned correctly - take the disc out and put it in again. You may get this Autorun option *(probably a good sign that it has burned correctly)*: [image: AutoRun Prompt showing 'Run wubi.exe']

Select 'Open folder to view files' and you should get:
 [image: There should be mutiple files in the disc folder, not one]

You can then eject the disc and put it into the computer you want to recover the files from. When booting, get the computer to boot from the CD/DVD drive. You said you had the following:

1. CD/DVD -  what you want it do, boot from a disc in the CD/DVD drive
2. +HDD - boot from the hard disk
3. LAN (or PXE **or Ethernet**) - boot from the internet - this means it will search the connected network for something to boot from, and will return errors if it can't find anything. See also: [Preboot Execution Environment](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment)
4. FDD - Floppy Disk Drive (probably) - is this computer that old? :-)

The only two options that are likely to work ar CD/DVD and HDD - the first will boot from the disc, what you need to

When booting the disc, you should get a purple screen then a screen with the Ubuntu logo. When prompted press 'Try Ubuntu'. This means that Ubuntu will run off the disc, and the memory in the computer - **any files you save to Ubuntu's won't be saved as this is in the computer's memory** - use a USB stick to save/copy to.

When the desktop loads, open the Nautilus file manager from the launcher on the left. Looking under 'Devices' you should see the entry for the computer's hard disk partitions, as well as a any connected USB drivers. The directory 'Users' *(or 'Documents and Settings' for Windows XP)* in the root of one of these drives should contain your user's files.

If you can't access the disk, you may need to do something else to get the data off of the disc.

---

### Recovering files

If you only have command line access to Ubuntu, you can run `mc` to use the midnight-command file manager:

[image: mc]

(You can run `mc -a` if the lines are not drawn properly)

This is a command line file manager - you can find out how to use it [here](http://www.trembath.co.za/mctutorial.html), also [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/midnight-commander-mc-guide-powerful-text-based-file-manager-for-unix/) - you can use the following:

1. Use Tab and the arrows keys to navigate
2. The function keys:

   ```
   F1 - help.
   F2 - user menu (to compress files etc)
   F3 - view (checking contents of a file i think)
   F5 - copy
   F6 - rename or move
   F7 - create a directory
   F8 - delete
   F9 - pull-down - accesses the menu bar at the top.
   F10 - quit. Closes mc, as well as mcedit and any unwanted open menu.
   ```
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to switch to and from command line - useful for running `mount` commands etc

Devices plugged into the computer should be automounted in the `media` directory - if not, you will need [mount them manually](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mounting-windows-partition-onto-ubuntu-linux/) - for example:

- To make a directory for the partition to mount to

  ```
  sudo mkdir /media/windows-partition
  ```
- To mount the partition - you can find the device (`/dev/sda2` for example) from the output of `sudo fdisk -l` or `sudo parted -l` - a large partiton (you can find sizes in `sudo parted -l`) formatted to NTFS or FAT should be the main windows partition. Your user files should be contained within 'Documents and Settings' in the root of the partition.

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/windows-partition/
  ```
- To unmount the partition, run

  ```
  sudo umount /media/windows-partition
  ```

You can then copy the files over using `mc` - copying should mean you can check whether you have the files you want afterwards.

Comment: The broken hard drive has the famous “click noise of death” including when it is fitted into (3) via (2).   I doubt if that hard drive still works.

When you refer to "disk" I guess you mean to acquire a blank CD disk.   I have never done that before so would be curious if there is anything I need to know in advance.

Comment: You need to get **DVD-R** disks usually, and you should be able to buy them in [spindle packs](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/verbatim-16x-speed-dvd-r-25-pack-a33ct) from some stationary/electronics stores. **DVD+R** can be variable in support, as far as I remember. You then need to burn the disk, there is a guide on doing so in Windows [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows).

Comment: I have recently purchased (4) = 2.5" Sata hard drive, and I've burned Ubuntu onto a DVD and changed the boot order in BIOS having DVD first. But when the computer is re-booted I keep getting this message; Intel UNDI, PXE-2.0 (build 082)
Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation

For Realtek RTL8139(X)/8130/810X PCI Fast Ethernet Controller v2.13 (020326)
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM.
Operating System not found

Comment: The error sound like u have booting by Ethernet set as first, not DVD... Try setting the boot order again. Instructions on making a bootable DVD on windows [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows), there is also [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD)guide on booting from a disc.

Comment: When I re-boot and press F12 I get Boot Menu 1. CD/DVD 2. +HDD 3. LAN 4. FDD <Enter Setup> I've searched my computer & the Internet for "Ethernet" but can't find anything. I'm lost and need more help.

Comment: I've checked the DVD in my other computer and there is only 1 file showing so it appears as if the DVD has been improperly burned.

Comment: I have downloaded Ubuntu-rescue-remix again and it appears as if it is no different to the copy burned onto the DVD. The download has 238838 KB the same as on the DVD. I cannot understand why my computer will not boot. I need help.

Comment: I have checked the guide on booting from a disc and the part where it refers to the disc not burned properly and that there should not be a single file, but that is referring to Ubuntu desktop.iso. I have burned Ubuntu-rescue-remix and downloaded a 2nd file and both only have a single file. desktop.iso and rescue-remix.iso appear to be different. Can somebody advise me how I can make rescue-remix.iso re-boot? Or tell me where to check for errors?

Comment: all the disks when burnt should not have only one file on the burnt disc, especially if it ends in '.iso', or is of that type. Try another sort of disc burning software/method. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto . You can also use a USB stick to install from - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows - bear in mind its contents may be wiped. Once u have disc/USB that works, u need to get the computer to boot from it, which means u have to do something to select what to boot from during start up.

Comment: I downloaded rescue-remix 3 times, 3rd from Cnet all 3 have single file in Downloads Folder & have 238,838 KB. I have noted (recent Ubuntu versions do not fit on to CD any more) a CD holds 600,000-700,000 KB. Does that mean downloads are not fully downloading? I bought blank DVD & it formatted. I opened windows side by side and clicked "Burn" in Downloads window. Still a single image. It appears it is not burning properly. I downloaded a DVD burner from http://www.iskysoft.us but get this message - dvd-creator_full1379.exe is not commonly downloaded & could harm your computer. Is it safe?

Comment: Don't use that, use [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/?page_id=5) - guide [here](http://www.eugenecomputergeeks.com/Chat-FAQ/How-do-I-Burn-Ubuntu-to-a-CD-from-Windows.html). I have just added a step-by-step guide to my answer.

Comment: I can now get as far as "Try Ubuntu" but usually when I click that I end up with a black screen, however there is a message that comes in that black screen saying "Disconnected - you are now offline network" which I assume refers to the Internet, but maybe not. Sometimes it goes passed the black screen to a window with icons down the left side and a window headed "Keyboard Shortcuts" Pressing Alt + F1 does nothing. Although no warnings, it appears an overheating problem but I can hear an internal fan & also feel warm air coming out. I've also put laptop on blocks for better ventilation.

Comment: The window with icons and the keyboard Shortcuts is the default Ubuntu 14.04 desktop on first login. Can you do anything with the desktop, or is it frozen? Also, how much memory (RAM) does the laptop have?

Comment: It freezes. It has maximum memory 2 something probably MB. I bought the laptop at the end of 2006.

Comment: It's a Toshiba L30 & I read the maximum RAM is 2 GB, although the sticks I installed are greater.

Comment: Does pressing Ctrl-Alt-F2 result in anything? Also, if you can't get it to work in any way, you could use [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) as an alternative - it uses a lighter desktop environment that it less likely to crash on older hardware.

Comment: OK I'll download Lubuntu. Is it OK to burn it onto the same DVD? And maybe I'll also burn Rescue-Remix on the same DVD. If all 3 are on the same DVD do I get a choice when the laptop boots up? Pressing Ctrl-Alt-F2 results in DOS prompt Ubuntu@Ubuntu:~$_

Comment: I'm sorry I think you can only write one iso to each DVD - Lubuntu should almost definitely work if the command prompt works on the Ubuntu disk works. Also, the Lubuntu iso should may be able to burnt to a CD as it is less than 700MB in size. As far as I know, using ubuntu rescue-remix should would be pretty much the same as clicking 'Try Ubuntu' and then pressing Ctrl-Alt-F2 (except a few things may need installing with `sudo apt-get install cdw gddrescue mc`) - see http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/taxonomy/term/3

Comment: For those with same problems burning DVD Win7 - After inserting DVD ignore autorun options & dont format & ignore other "Burn" words - Select file-Open (at top)-Windows disc image burner-Click-Check "Verify disc after burning"-Click "Burn". Ive burned Lubuntu & Rescue Remix 2 separate discs. Both appear OK. Lubuntu I dont know how to achieve my mission to transfer files from damaged HDD to good HDD. Rescue Remix I end up with DOS prompt Ubuntu@Ubuntu:~$_ & dont know what to enter. Part way through it says to enter "live" but it does not recognise that word. Wilf do you know what I should enter

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already have a second working laptop *AND* a SATA/USB converter, you don't necessarily need to buy another drive - you can transfer it directly onto the new laptop (if it has space).

1. Remove broken drive from old laptop.
2. Connect broken drive to the SATA/USB converter.  (Note: if the old hard drive isn't SATA, this won't work and you'd need to do things differently).
3. Use data recovery tools on the new laptop to try to copy stuff off the broken drive onto the drive inside the new laptop.

If you want to use Ubuntu for data recovery (because it's free), then you will need to  be able to load Ubuntu onto a bootable DVD or bootable USB stick.  Once you have that you can boot the new laptop with Ubuntu.

To boot from USB or the DVD without removing the internal disk in the new laptop, you'd have to reconfigure the boot order in the BIOS setup of the broken laptop.

Once you have Ubuntu running, you start the data recovery.

- Firstly, you may be able to mount the broken hard drive to copy things from it.  Sometimes a hard drive won't boot but it can still otherwise be mounted from another OS.
- Otherwise if the drive is more heavily corrupted you may need to use [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) - available in Ubuntu - to do recovery.  How to use testdisk is another question probably outside of the scope here.
- Don't write anything *to* the broken hard drive, even if you do manage to access it.  Only copy from it to another drive (eg the drive inside the new laptop).